# how aright use function with echo and return?

Tags: php

Code ONE (WORK ARIGHT):

```
function Hello( $rel ) {
   $res = mysqli("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
   $result = $res->num_rows;
   if ( $rel == 1 ) {
      print $result;
   } elseif ( $rel == 2 ) {
      echo $result;
   } elseif ( $rel == 3 ) {
      return $result;
   } else { 
      return $result;
   }
}

$pr = HELLO(3);
echo $pr;
```

It code work aright.

Then I wanted to do one function to process the data and output the result.

Code:

```
function out( $rel, $result ) {
   if ( $rel == 1 ) {
      print $result; 
   } elseif ( $rel == 2 ) {
      echo $result;
   } elseif ( $rel == 3 ) {
      return $result;
   } else { 
      return $result;
   }
}

function Hello( $rel ) {
   $res = mysqli("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
   $result = $res->num_rows;
   out( $rel, $result )
}

$pr = HELLO(3);
echo $pr;
```

But now code not work(not show results on line `echo $pr;`)...

***Tell me please why i have error and how write aright?***

*P.S.: i not know that need use return before function. 
Thanks all for my new knowledge.*

Comment: Change `out($rel,$result)` in `return out($rel,$result);`.

Comment: This is a beautiful question.

Comment: I really hope this is example code and not your actual functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not return the value in the second code.

you need to use like this:

```
return out($rel,$result).
```

The return is in the second function, second function returns the value to function first, now function first also needs to return, so u need to add return there too.

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to add `return` to `out($rel,$result)`

as it is right now, your `Hello()` function doesn't have return value.